# Как из select брать переменные и работать с ними далее (MYSQL)?

Tags: mysql

Ребят хелп)))) . Данная процедура по сути должна находить должников , если у должника есть счет на балансе то нужно отнимать оплату за месяц и добавить в другую таблицу за какой месяц было оплачено и какая сумма.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getdebet`()
BEGIN
declare contructt int;
declare clientt int ;
declare paymonth decimal;
declare payformonth date;
 select c.contruct_id,c.client_id,c.pay_month,max(p.pay_for_month) 
 into contructt,clientt,paymonth,payformonth
 from client t inner join contruct c on t.client_id = c.client_id 
 inner join payments_for_rent p on c.contruct_id = p.contruct_id 
 where p.contruct_id not in
( 
select c.contruct_id
from kvd.client t 
inner join kvd.CONTRUCT c on t.client_id = c.client_id
inner join kvd.payments_for_rent p on p.contruct_id = c.contruct_id
where (to_days(sysdate()) - to_days(p.pay_for_month))<30
group by c.contruct_id 
)
group by c.contruct_id ;
-- в выше написанном селекте находит должников, дело в том, что переменные
-- он может брать только с одной строки. Как это завернуть в цикл, чтоб для 
-- каждой строки брал переменные и выполнял последующие действия???????


  if((select balance_$ from balance where client_id = clientt)>0)  
then 
    update balance set balance_$ = balance_$ - paymonth where client_id  = clientt; 
    insert into payments_for_rent(contruct_id,client_id,payments,insert_date,pay_for_month) 
    values(contructt,clientt,paymonth,sysdate(),DATE_ADD(payformonth,interval 1 MONTH));

   end if;



        END
```

Comment: что такое "getd"? и что там за второе слово, следующее за ним oO?

Comment: Я бы еще добавил информацию о таблицах

Comment: И точно стоит заменить условие `(to_days(sysdate()) - to_days(p.pay_for_month))<30` на что то вроде `p.pay_for_month > sysdate() - interval 30 day` что бы избавится от применения функции к колонке, которая замедляет запрос

Comment: триггер тут не нужен так как  идет сначала пополнение баланса а потом уже процедура запускается и распределяет по неоплаченным месяцам

Comment: Когда  я вижу сначала update, а потом сразу insert в некую таблицу детализации, я сразу предполагаю, что одна операция без другой не происходит никогда. Я имею ввиду, что если вставка в таблицу payments_for_rent всегда тянет за собой изменение баланса, то триггер просто напрашивается, что бы случайно не забыть где нибудь изменить баланс при вставке записи. И тогда процедура выглядит "вставляем все недостающие месячные списания" и о балансе задумываемся только в ключе, что бы не вставлять списания при отрицательном балансе

Comment: тут идея заключается в том чтобы создать хранимую процедуру , когда человек пополнит баланс или даже нет , чтобы автоматически каждый последующий месяц вычитывал из основного баланса нужную сумму и если даже баланс станет минусовой все норм они и считаются должниками

Comment: я  не всю процедуру залил , но там и за второй и за последующий месяц будет списывать до окончания контракта . + штрафы

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было завернуть данный селект в курсор 
таким образом :

```
declare done int default false;
declare cursor_select cursor for
 select c.contruct_id,c.client_id,c.pay_month,max(p.pay_for_month) 
 into contructt,clientt,paymonth,payformonth
 from client t inner join contruct c on t.client_id = c.client_id 
 inner join payments_for_rent p on c.contruct_id = p.contruct_id 
 where p.contruct_id not in
( 
select c.contruct_id
from kvd.client t 
inner join kvd.CONTRUCT c on t.client_id = c.client_id
inner join kvd.payments_for_rent p on p.contruct_id = c.contruct_id
where (to_days(sysdate()) - to_days(p.pay_for_month))<30
group by c.contruct_id 
)
group by c.contruct_id ;
declare continue handler for not found set done = true ;
open cursor_select;
read_loop: LOOP
Fetch cursor_select into contructt,clientt,paymonth,payformonth;
if done then
leave read_loopl;

-- здесь insert-ы и update-ы 

end loop;
close cursor_select;

End
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]